# Cast void pointer to double without knowing its type in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting, void

I need to write a function which takes as parameters a void pointer (representing an array) and an integer which represents the length of the array. In the function, I need to cast this void pointer into a double one. The problem is that the void pointer can represent an array of integers or floats or doubles.
So the following is obviously not working in case the void pointer represents an array of integers or floats:

```
void foo(void *v,int n){
    double *values;

    values=(double*)v;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        printf("%f\n",values[i]);
}
```

so this will print the correct output:

```
foo((double[]){1,2,3,4},4);
```

and this will print a wrong output:

```
foo((int[]){1,2,3,4},4);
foo((float[]){1,2,3,4},4);
```

So... can I correctly cast the void pointer to a double one only knowing that it can be an array of integers or floats or doubles? And is it necessary to have the length of the array or I can calculate it somehow?
P.s. without using callbacks

Comment: Is another parameter an option, carrying the information on what type to assume? This is by the way an example why the temptingly "versatile" void pointers usually turn out to be a trap... What you are trying to do seems to be an "overloaded" function, which is an OOP concept, i.e. C++ would be the language which would provide that to you. Is using C++ an option?

Comment: The binary representation of an `int`, `float` and `double` are different, so when you do `(double*)v` you say to the compiler *treat this as a double* and that's exactly what it does. If you are not passing doubles, you end up with horrible errors.

Comment: You can sort of do this by making `foo` a macro, and [using the `_Generic` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40096584/c11-generic-usage).

Comment: @Yunnosch No, unfortunately it's not an option... maybe the best option is to take a double pointer as parameter and let who calls the function casting its array to double...

Comment: One way would be to pass the type of array as a third argument and the function would then decide how to cast to elements depending on the type.

Answer (score 0):

> can I correctly cast the void pointer to a double one only knowing that it can be an array of integers or floats or doubles?

No, you cannot. You need to pass the type information somehow.

> And is it necessary to have the length of the array or I can calculate it somehow?

It's necessary to pass the length.

---

You can "hide" the information inside a struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

enum etype { INTEGER, FLOAT, DOUBLE };
struct data {
    void *values;
    size_t n;
    enum etype type;
};

void foo(struct data *x) {
    int *xd = x->values;
    float *xf = x->values;
    double *xg = x->values;
    for (int k = 0; k < x->n; k++) {
        switch (x->type) {
            default: printf("%g ", xg[k]); break;
            case FLOAT: printf("%f ", xf[k]); break;
            case INTEGER: printf("%d ", xd[k]); break;
        }
    }
    puts("");
}

int main(void) {
    struct data x;

    x.values = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
    ((int*)(x.values))[0] = 42;
    ((int*)(x.values))[1] = -1;
    ((int*)(x.values))[2] = 0;
    ((int*)(x.values))[3] = 999;
    x.n = 4;
    x.type = INTEGER;
    foo(&x);

    x.values = calloc(4, sizeof(float));
    x.type = FLOAT;
    float tmp = 3.14159;
    memcpy(((float*)(x.values))+1, &tmp, sizeof (float));
    foo(&x);
    free(x.values);

    x.values = calloc(4, sizeof(double));
    x.type = DOUBLE;
    ((double*)(x.values))[2] = 2.7182818;
    foo(&x);
    free(x.values);
}
```

See [code running on ideone](https://ideone.com/DTMMbW)